# Is there a way to plot a curve of best fit without function? Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, spline, smoothing

I need to plot a smooth curve of best fit but all the methods I've found use scipy.optimize.curve_fit(), and this requires knowing the function relating x and y. Is there a simpler way to do it for basic scatter plots?

What Im trying to get the curve for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

x = range(30)
y = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 12, 13, 14, 12, 11, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]

plot.plot(x, y, "o")
plot.show()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `the curve` for a situation where you don't know the function? Your data appears fairly gaussian -- are you looking for a gaussian fit to those data?

Comment: Yes, but wouldnt I need to know the specific gaussian function relating x to y to get an accurate curve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typically to smooth without a guess of a generating function, people use a spline.  Here's an example using your data:[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
import numpy as np

x = range(30)
y = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 12, 13, 14, 12, 11, 9, 6, 5, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]

s = UnivariateSpline(x, y, s=5)
xs = np.linspace(0, 29, 100)
ys = s(xs)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

As you've probably guessed, the keyword `s` is used to set how closely the fit matches the data, where `s=0` will go through every point.

Splines basically fit a simple function to local sets of points from the curve and then match the derivatives at the boundaries to connect these local curves so the end result looks smooth.

There are a variety of spline routines to choose from in scipy.

Comment: Great.  From the comments to your main question it seemed that you might prefer to fit a Gaussian, which is also possible, but is very different than this solution.  Please clarify if you do want to do a full fit.

Comment: slightly annoying for my data that `x` must be strictly increasing for the input to `UnivariateSpline`.  in my case, i'll just average the y-values for a given x before passing to `UnivariateSpline`, but it would be nice to have a single function that automatically took care of this.

Comment: This information helped me a lot! For future users, you should be aware the fit is cubic by default -which is not always what you want-, pass the argument "k" to have control over the fit order. Very important...